# Using libparson to parse arrays

Tags: c, json, parsing, jsonparser

I am writing a C application running on Linux which uses libparson to parse JSON files.

https://github.com/mofywong/libparson

I have the following JSON file which gets read into my application into a `char*` called `reply` .

```
{
    "entries": 
    [   {
            "timestampEnd": "2022-02-11T10:19:00.00Z",
            "timestampStart": "2022-02-11T10:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 1001
        },
        {
            "timestampEnd": "2022-02-11T14:47:00.00Z",
            "timestampStart": "2022-02-11T13:19:00.000Z",
            "value": 2000
        }
    ]
}
```

I am struggling to correctly parse the entries array. My code attempt is as follows :

```
JSON_Value*  root_value         = json_parse_string(reply);
JSON_Array*  entries            = json_value_get_array(root_value);

for (int i = 0; i < json_array_get_count(entries); i++)
{
    printf("Inside array parsing loop\n");
    JSON_Object *entry         = json_array_get_object(entries, i);

    const char* timestampStart = json_object_dotget_string(entry, "timestampStart");
    const char* timestampEnd   = json_object_dotget_string(entry, "timestampEnd");
    unsigned int value         = (unsigned int)json_object_dotget_number(entry, "value");
    // process values               
}
```

Execution never goes inside the loop. What am I doing wrong exactly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried printing `json_array_get_count(entries)` to see if it gives the correct count? It looks like you are converting the root object which is a JSON object into an array. You have to get the `entries` value of the root object.

Comment: @Shahriar Thanks for your reply. I was following other examples and JSON_Array*  entries = json_value_get_array(root_value); was how it was implemented. I feel that I am missing something silly here indeed, but I don't spot it

Answer (score 0):

As I said, you are converting the root object which is a JSON object into an array. You have to get the entries value of the root object:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parson.h"

const char* reply =
    "{\n"
    "    \"entries\": \n"
    "    [   {\n"
    "            \"timestampEnd\": \"2022-02-11T10:19:00.00Z\",\n"
    "            \"timestampStart\": \"2022-02-11T10:00:00.000Z\",\n"
    "            \"value\": 1001\n"
    "        },\n"
    "        {\n"
    "            \"timestampEnd\": \"2022-02-11T14:47:00.00Z\",\n"
    "            \"timestampStart\": \"2022-02-11T13:19:00.000Z\",\n"
    "            \"value\": 2000\n"
    "        }\n"
    "    ]\n"
    "}";

int main()
{
    JSON_Value* root_value = json_parse_string(reply);
    JSON_Array* entries = json_object_dotget_array(json_value_get_object(root_value), "entries");

    for (int i = 0; i < json_array_get_count(entries); i++)
    {
        printf("Inside array parsing loop\n");
        JSON_Object* entry = json_array_get_object(entries, i);

        const char* timestampStart = json_object_dotget_string(entry, "timestampStart");
        const char* timestampEnd = json_object_dotget_string(entry, "timestampEnd");
        unsigned int value = (unsigned int)json_object_dotget_number(entry, "value");
        // process values
    }
}
```

The difference is in this code: `json_object_dotget_array(json_value_get_object(root_value), "entries");`.